# WPML language switch not redirecting to right domain

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, wpml

I got an WP installation with WPML, i did set them on different domains so domain.com and domain.nl.

When i'm on a page with the following url: domain.com/free the switch will let it go to domain.nl/gratis.
But when i'm on domain.nl/gratis it points to domain.nl/free. So when going back from a not default language to the default language it's not taking the correct domain.

Someone ever had the same issue? Or any clue how to solve this / where to look.

Answer (score 0):

I had the wp-config.php set the site urls with HTTP_HOST which lead into this problem.